# How do I restore a deleted command in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I accidentally overwrote the file `/usr/bin/mdmon`. How can I undo this or reinstall the file?

My system is Arco Linux I3 edition, Macbook Air 2017.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Find out which package the file is a part of, then re-install that package.  Arcolinux is an Arch derivative, so it uses the `pacman` package manager.  Type, as root, in a terminal window:

```
pacman -Qo /usr/bin/mdmon
```

Say, the file owner `/` package is `mdadm`.  Reinstall it:

```
pacman -S --force mdadm
```

Comment: PS: It *is* really `mdadm`: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/mdadm/files/